# Javascript String to Enum

Tags: javascript, enums

Say I have an enum that looks like this:

```
enum Role {
  Cleaner = 'CLEANER',
  Driver = 'DRIVER',
  Gardner = 'GARDNER'
}
```

At some point my enum is turned into a string:

```
CLEANER
```

From the string value how would I turn it back to enum like so?

```
Role.Cleaner
```

Comment: `enum Role` isn't JavaScript, so it's not really clear what you're asking for here.

Answer (score 4):

You'd implement enum with an object literal, like this...

```
const Roles = {
  Cleaner: 'CLEANER',
  Driver: 'DRIVER',
  Gardner: 'GARDNER'
}
```

And you can get a key from a value like this...

```
const roleForValue = value => {
  return Object.keys(Roles).find(r => Roles[r] === value)
}
```

So...

```js
const Roles = {
  Cleaner: 'CLEANER',
  Driver: 'DRIVER',
  Gardner: 'GARDNER'
}

const roleForValue = value => {
  return Object.keys(Roles).find(r => Roles[r] === value)
}

let value = 'DRIVER'
let role = roleForValue(value)

console.log(role)
console.log(Roles[role])
```

Comment: If you'd want the actual Role type in TypeScript, you would call `Roles[roleForValue(value)]` in addition to the above.